# How can I get the job-immediate-alerts stsadm property setting to work?

Tags: 2007, alert, stsadm

Despite my running the following command:

`stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-immediate-alerts -pv "Every 1 minutes between 0 and 59"`

the immediate alerts timer job runs every five minutes.

What do I need to do to get it to run every minute?

Answer (score 1):

I forget to include the -url switch.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262432(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have a custom schedule. You have to pick one of the existing scheduling options available in the dropdown and/or documented at the link above.